# Drupal login issue on pantheon server

Tags: php, session, drupal, authentication, pantheon

We have a drupal site running on pantheon server.
We are facing issue with login in site.

We are able to login in site, but whenever we open any other page except "user" page, it shows that you are not logged in.
Again we open user page, it shows as logged in user.

We can not determine what is the issue.

Please help us in this issue.

Comment: Sounds like a cache? Not much to go off here. Like... your server's configuration or Drupal's extensions? Do you have varnish on the server?

Comment: Yes, Our drupal is on pantheon server. And pantheon, By default provide varnish

Comment: We have not configured any new module or change any configuration file

Comment: Sounds like varnish is sending the cached page, then. Have you configured this Drupal install to work with varnish? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48113/cant-login-to-drupal-after-varnish-install-reverse-proxy
https://www.drupal.org/node/1196916

Comment: Previously, it was working fine. But last week, pantheon people has changed our IP. From that day, we are facing issue. Please help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be caching issue on server side.
Try to disable all caching, and disable or clear varnish cache.

Then use Drush [rebuild registry](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) command from terminal

```
drush rr
```

You can find more information [here](https://pantheon.io/docs/articles/local/drupal-drush-command-line-utility/). [How to execute Drush commands on Pantheon.](https://pantheon.io/docs/articles/local/drupal-drush-command-line-utility/)

If above solution not works then try to [debugging cache on Pantheon](https://pantheon.io/docs/articles/sites/varnish/debugging-cache/)